# How should I use the HTMLOptionElement.Option() constructor?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an option to a select element like this

```
<select id="select-title"></select>
<script>
  let s = document.querySelector('#select-title');
  let optionElementReference = new HTMLOptionElement.Option('option1');
  s.add(optionElementReference);
</script>
```

But I get (Chrome 54) "Uncaught TypeError: HTMLOptionElement.Option is not a constructor(…)"

I thought I should be able to do this because of the following piece of documentation (although I have found no example of such usage). I guess I might be making a simple mistake somewhere.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement

**HTMLOptionElement.Option()** Is a constructor creating an HTMLOptionElement object. It has four values: the text to display, text, the value associated, value, the value of defaultSelected, and the value of selected. The last three values are optional.

Comment: you can use just `new Option('option1')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

Comment: @Punit thank you, I knew someone here would point out my mistake quickly.

Comment: The part you wrote in bold in what you quoted from MDN links to the explanation how to use the constructor ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `HTMLOptionElement.`

```js
let s = document.querySelector('#select-title');
let optionElementReference = new Option('option1');
s.add(optionElementReference);
```

```html
<select id="select-title"></select>
```